# Python 2.7.3 Why do sets of tuples with repeated elements behave this way?

Tags: python, set, tuples

Why is it that if I try to create a set of tuples in python, e.g.

```
>>> print set((0,1))
set([0, 1])
>>> print set((0,0))
set([0])
>>> print set([(0,0)])
set([(0, 0)])
```

the tuple that has repeated elements collapses into a non-tuple? Why does putting brackets give the desired result?

Comment: `[...]` is a list not set. set only remove the duplicates not list.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` constructor takes an *iterable* that provides the elements for the set. If you provide the `set` constructor a tuple like `(0, 1)`, the *elements* of that tuple will become the elements of the set, that is; in the first case the elements will be 0 and 1; in the second case there is only element: 0.

In the 3rd case you are providing the constructor with a list, whose single element is the tuple `(0, 0)`; the resulting set will have the same elements as the list (that is, the tuple `(0, 0)`).

If you find the numerous brackets confusing, you can use the `{ }` for a set literal Python 2.**7** and Python 3.x:

```
>>> {(0,0)}
set([(0, 0)])
```

---

The `repr` of a `set` in Python 2 adds to some confusion - in Python 3 the distinction between the cases is clearer:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) 
>>> set((0,1))
{0, 1}
>>> set((0,0))
{0}
>>> set([(0,0)])
{(0, 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a nested iterable and the set function accepts a single iterable:

```
print set([(0,0)]) # there is no other occurance of (0, 0) in list
```